# Match multiple lines with multiline regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to match a text with multiple lines. My problem is that the line breaks can be different types (\n,\r\n or \r). Currently I'm using `(?:\r?\n|\r)` but wanted to replace it with `$^` in multiline mode but it doesn't seem to work when they are not at the beginning or ending of a string.

For example `A$^B` does not match

```
A
B

A
B
```

I am using [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/eQ6vT7) to test it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$` and `^` don't match the linebreak characters themselves, they only match the *position* at the end/start of a line. You need to use something like

```
A[\r\n]+B
```

Comment: Okay that's somewhat unfortunate. But at least now I know that I can't make it any easier detecting line breaks. Why is B escaped?

Comment: @nhahtdh: Oh, thanks for fixing my regex! No idea where that backslash came from.

Answer (score 2):

If you are ok with any whitespace

`A\s*B`   - can optionally have whitespace
`A\s+B`   - must have some whitespace

`A[\r\n]+B`   - must have at least one newline character \r or \n - would also match multiple blank lines between a and b

Comment: `\s` might be another nice solution, but I have to test that with my complete regex.